# Node.js leak in pipeline

Tags: node.js, pipeline

I wrote a gateway for my microservices system. 
Gateway was written in node.js

This gateway forwards the request to inside microservices, and responds client after getting result of their processing. 
But memory consumed by this gateway continually increased, 24Mb increased every hour.

Could you help me to clarify why:
The following is code:

```
var express = require('express');
var requestify = require('requestify');
var app     = express();

var request = require('request');
var config  = require('./config.js');
var API_ERROR = 'error';
var DISCOVERY_NOTHING = 'nothing' ;
var TIMEOUT = 10000 ;//ms

function registerEntry(path,entryId) {
        app.use(path, function(req, res) {
            requestify.get(config.discovery+"?service_id="+entryId, {timeout:TIMEOUT}).then( function(response) { 
                var apiUrl  = response.getBody() ;
                if(apiUrl==DISCOVERY_NOTHING) {
                    res.send(API_ERROR);
                }   

                var url     = apiUrl + req.url ; 
                console.log(url);
                req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res).on('error', function(e) {
                    res.send(API_ERROR);
                }); 
            }); 
        }); 
}

registerEntry('/authen','altp.authen') ;
registerEntry('/profile','altp.profile');
registerEntry('/question','altp.question');
registerEntry('/gameplay','altp.gameplay');
registerEntry('/admin','altp.admin');

app.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('listening at 80');
});
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the code do not use image! I haven't time to rewrite your code.

Comment: I had a similar issue when developing my own microservice gateway (https://github.com/slebetman/typhos) until I moved to using http-proxy to do the proxying (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) I never did manage to figure out where the leak was coming from.

Comment: @Michelem: I added the full code

Comment: @slebetman: Thank you, that is good suggestion, I will try, but first I want to address this problem to avoid it in the future .